# Query to find and replace text in all tables and fields of a mysql db

Tags: mysql, replace

I need to run a query to find and replace some text in all tables of a mysql database.

I found this query, but it only looks for the text in the tbl_name table and just in the **column** field.

```
update tbl_name set column=REPLACE(column, 'fuschia', 'fuchsia');
```

I need it to look in all tables and all fields: (everywhere in the database)

Comment: You can get an idea [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13259/sql-command-to-remove-prefix-from-a-set-of-tables)

Comment: This is a bit strange though, can you elaborate as why you need to do this, I am only curious.

Comment: Then I have to loop every table. Thanks, I get it done. @dezco: would you mind to change your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `information_schema` database to generate the script.

Collect all columns from every table of every database that have the following criteria:

- Exclude the following databases:

  - `information_schema`
  - `performance_schema`
  - `mysql`
- `COLUMN_TYPE` values with one of the following characteristics:

  - starts with `CHAR(`
  - starts with `VARCHAR(`
  - ends with `TEXT` (`TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `LONGTEXT`)

Here is the query to get those columns

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
AND (column_type LIKE 'char(%' OR column_type LIKE 'varchar(%' OR column_type LIKE '%text');
```

Using the above query, construct a set of queries that outputs SQL for converting `fuschia` to `fuchsia`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,
' SET ',column_name,'=REPLACE(',column_name,',''fuschia'',''fuchsia'');')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
AND (column_type LIKE 'char(%'
OR column_type LIKE 'varchar(%'
OR column_type LIKE '%text');
```

Take that query and send its output to a text file. Import text into mysql:

```
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,"
SQL="${SQL}' SET \`',column_name,'\`=REPLACE(\`',column_name,'\`,''fuschia'',''fuchsia'');') "
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.columns WHERE "
SQL="${SQL} table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema') "
SQL="${SQL} AND (column_type LIKE 'char(%' "
SQL="${SQL} OR column_type LIKE 'varchar(%'"
SQL="${SQL} OR column_type LIKE '%text');"
mysql -u... -p... -ANe"${SQL}" > GlobalReplace_fuschia_to_fuchsia.sql
less GlobalReplace_fuschia_to_fuchsia.sql
```

If the file looks good, feel free to execute it.

Give it a Try !!!